# how to pass from combobox value to

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

Somehow I managed to make that id isn't shown in the combobox, but then how to make that when I press the button ok I could get the id value? Using `String from = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();` when the button is pressed doesn't work. I get `String code = (String) item.getValue();` the id I needed, but how do I pass it to the next query?

```
public void select() {

         try {
            String sql = "select * from category";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

        jComboBox1.addItem(new Item<String>(rs.getString("mkid"), rs.getString("name")));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox jComboBox1 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                Item item = (Item) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                String code = (String) item.getValue();
                System.out.println(code);
            }
        });


    }


    The item

     public class Item<V> implements Comparable<Item>
     {
    private V value;
    private String description;


    public Item(V value, String description)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }


    public V getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public int compareTo(Item item)
    {
        return getDescription().compareTo(item.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        Item item = (Item)object;
        return value.equals(item.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return value.hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return description;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an listener to your button and then add the code to get your combo box value to a string.

```
       JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");  
       okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox jComboBox1 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            Item item = (Item) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            String code = (String) item.getValue();
            System.out.println(code);
         }          
      });
```

Comment: Im using jFrame so I added the button then i added private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) and then i should put this code?

Comment: yes, you can add the code to get your combo box values alone in your ActionPerformed() method. i.e. the last three lines of the code in the answer :)

Comment: okey so it looks like this:
 `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 JComboBox jComboBox1 = (JComboBox) evt.getSource();
            Item item = (Item) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            String code = (String) item.getValue();
}`
and now i tried to use String code in my querry but i get tons of errors. Querry looks `pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from table where mk_id = '" + code + "'");`And some errors like**java.lang.ClassCastException:javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox**

Comment: JComboBox jComboBox1 = (JComboBox) evt.getSource(); this makes the exception. 

since you have get the selected item value, you can use it alone

Comment: so how to use it alone?

Comment: can u pls just remove the line causing the error and try running it

Comment: could i use same thing for jtable? because i need to hide product id too ?

Comment: you want to get an item from table or what? could u be specific

Comment: nah im okey, just needed to hide id column from table. So i used this `table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));` :) Thanks for help!